# How to use Python to Interface with z/OS Services to Automate Manual Processes

Tags: python, interface, mainframe

I'm trying to automate some manual process on Mainframe, for that I want  to use Python.  I'm aware of some interfaces using FTP via ftplib.  My immediate task is to

Query existing job status/ log in spool...

Any documentation or help is appreciated.

Comment: The doc for `ftplib` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html).

Comment: What spooling facility is used on the mainframe? You would need to query it using a language that the spooling facility supports e.g. Rexx. You could use your python script to kick off a Rexx, or whatever, program to query the spool and return your data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054151/x3270-connection-and-programming/27095790#27095790 ... try PY3270

Comment: Accessing job related tasks can be accomplished via REST APIs or using Ansible Modules.  You can find Ansible modules here: https://ansible-collections.github.io/ibm_zos_core/ or direct REST APIs here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.izua700/IZUHPINFO_API_RESTJOBS.htm

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the z/OSMF jobs REST APIs?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.izua700/IZUHPINFO_API_RESTJOBS.htm

You can use python to issue REST calls to get what you need.

Since you're interested in using python, you should also be aware of the Z Open Automation Utilities (no charge!)

This is a set of utilities that help manage mvs through shell commands in Unix System Services, Java, python, Ansible...

Here is an introductory link - be sure to use the side-bar on the left and expand the code examples, there are examples using the utilities on datasets and jobs.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKFYE_1.0.2/zoautil_purpose.html